# how to compare an integer and an std_logic vector

Tags: vhdl

I have an array of signals. I want to write to the appropriate cell in the array when a signal which is the "selector" is equal to the cells number. To save on writing and code lines I generate the assignment in a generate loop:

```
read_data_signals_gen: for i in 0 to (CAU_num -1) generate

    v_direction_sig(i)(0) <=  DATA_IN when (chosen_flow_sig = i) and (read_state = st_read_v_direction_0) else
                              v_direction_sig(i)(0);
    v_direction_sig(i)(1) <=  DATA_IN when (chosen_flow_sig = i) and (read_state = st_read_v_direction_1) else
                              v_direction_sig(i)(1);
    v_direction_sig(i)(2) <=  DATA_IN when (chosen_flow_sig = i) and (read_state = st_read_v_direction_2) else
                              v_direction_sig(i)
  ...
end generation read_data_signals_gen;
```

chosen_flow_sig is an `std_logic_vector (1 downto 0)` and gets `"00"`, `"01"`, `"10"` or `"11"` to denote the number of the cell, And `CAU_num` is an `integer` constant equal to 4. How do I create the comparison inside the `when` statement so that an integer number will be equal to its binary translation?

And a related question. Is there a way to perform the following code:

```
type  BitArray is array (natural range <>) of std_logic;

sel_sig : std_logic_vector(0 to 1);
bit_arr : BitArray(0 to 3)

sel_sig <= "00"
bit_arr(sel_sig) <= '1'  -- HOW TO PERFORM THIS?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably looking for

`to_integer(unsigned(sel_sig))`

e.g.

`bit_arr(to_integer(unsigned(sel_sig))) <= '1'`

or

`if to_integer(unsigned(sel_sig))=12 then ...`

Comment: Can I use it in a comparison?

Comment: You can use it as a regular integer, also in a comparison.

Answer (score 2):

If `chosen_flow_sig` represents a number, use a numerical type for it (`unsigned` or `integer` for example).  If you use `std_logic_vector` you're giving yourself pain that you don't need!

http://parallelpoints.com/node/3

Comment: `chosen_flow_sig` is created by a component I made (It a logic implementation of my selection algorithm). Can a component return an integer?

Comment: Yes, you can have whatever types you like on the ports of an entity.  It even synthesises :)

Comment: Martin, Thanks very much for that link. It explains and solves a pletora of frustrations I've had for a long time. I changed my coding style accordingly. Code is cleaner easier to read.

Comment: Thanks Sylvain - glad to be of service :)